# sorting two dimensional array... exception occurred (C++)

Tags: c++, sorting

while solving problem, Sorting two dimensional arrays was needed. I used merge sort, and set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int*sorted[1000]; 
void merge(int** list, int left, int mid, int right); 
void merge_sort(int** list, int left, int right);
int main(void) {
    int N;
    vector <int> L, H; 
    int l, h, max = 0, max_position, highest, highest_position = 0, area = 0;   cin >> N;
    int** info = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * N); 

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        info[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); 
        }
    }
    merge_sort(info, 0, N - 1); 


}
void merge(int** list, int left, int mid, int right) {
    int i, j, k, l; 
    i = left; j = mid + 1; k = left; 

    for (int s = 0; s < 7; s++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < 2; v++) {
            cout << list[s][v] << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n'; 
    }


    while (i <= mid && j <= right) {
        if (list[i][1] <= list[j][1])   // exception occured 
        {
            sorted[k++] = list[i++]; 
        }
        else { 
            sorted[k++] = list[j++];
        }
    }
    if (i > mid) // 1번째 array를 다 쓴 경우 
    {
        for (l = j; l <= right; l++) {
            sorted[k++] = list[l];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (l = i; l <= mid; l++) {
            sorted[k++] = list[l]; 
        }
    }
    for (l = left; l <= right; l++) {
        list[l] = sorted[k]; //  I think problem is related with this line 
    }

}
void merge_sort(int** list, int left, int right) {
    int mid; 
    if (left < right) {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        merge_sort(list, left, mid);
        merge_sort(list, mid + 1, right);
        merge(list, left, mid, right); 
    }
}
```

I assigned sorted array which is needed while sorting as interger pointer array, because I thought I need to assign addressees of each rows of the two dimensional array.

But problem seems to say that my basic thought related with pointer is wrong. Does anyone can help me with this?

Comment: `int** info = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);` -- `info[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);` -- Why didn't you use `std::vector` here?  If you did that, you may have a fighting chance of figuring out the issue, since `vector` has an `at()` function that checks array bounds.

Comment: I don't see any sets here! was malloc to supposed create one? perhaps you need std's set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it isn't really sorting 2D array, just array of pairs of ints.
You compare them by the second element. Another thing, you really don't want to use malloc nor new in this case. So, let's go through your solution improving it slowly.

1. Remove unnecessary mallocs.

`malloc` is a remaining C function, that shouldn't be used (almost) at all in C++ code. In C++ you have `new` doing similar thing, but you shouldn't be doing that either! Simply use `std::vector` that allocates under the hood, takes care of memory management and frees it for you. (Note, that you forgot to free the memory yourself).

```
// in main:
std::vector<std::vector<int>> info;
// set the first dimension, how many "rows" you need
info.resize(N);
// for each "row" change "column" size to 2
for (std::vector<int>& v : info) v.resize(2);
```

Remember, pass vector by reference to avoid copies!

2. Replace the 2nd dimension with `std::pair` / `struct`

In case you always know one of the dimensions, it's likely you are just sorting pairs / tuples of numbers, or some meaningful "objects".

So you replace the above code with:

```
// in main:
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> info;
// only one dimension, how many pairs of ints this vector holds
info.resize(N);
```

If these are numbers that represent something, like for example, ID and age of a book, you keep them in a struct.

```
// below includes, in global scope:

struct BookInfo {
  int age;
  int id;
};

// in main
std::vector<BookInfo> info;
// only one dimension, how many book infos this vector holds
info.resize(N);
```

3. Use the standard library!

In standard library, you have a std::sort function. It can take as a parameter, how you wanna compare the elements - in your case, by the second value of the pair.

So you can sort everything by first creating a function that compares two elements:

```
bool compareBookInfos(const BookInfo& b1, const BookInfo& b2) {
  // return true, if b1 should be before b2 in sorted array
  return b1.id < b2.id;
}
```

or the same for pairs:

```
bool compareIntPairBy2nd(const std::pair<int, int>& p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2) {
  // return true, if p1 should be before p2 in sorted array
  return p1.second < p2.second;
}
```

Now, call the `std::sort` method:

```
  std::sort(info.begin(), info.end(), compareBookInfos);
```

and you are done, in just a few lines of code!

If it's a task to write own sorting function, `std::vector` of pairs/structs should still improve your code and help you debug the problem, possibly giving better diagnostics.

Comment: For any more experienced reader - you can use std::vector constructor isntead of resizing it, I just wanted to be verbose to make sure the code is understandable for a beginner.

Comment: Compare functions can be replaced with lambda - same as before, don't want to put too much stuff in the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your kindful explanation. I learned C in my school and almost a beginner for C++ so I misused malloc function in C++ language. But still I want to know why my first code has got wrong . Can you explain it simply for me?

Comment: The line that you marked as the one you think is wrong, is indeed wrong. However, it's not the only problem. Let's go through the code, making gradual improvements (and ignoring 2D malloc for now).
1. The program will crash, if you sort more than 1000 numbers, cause your "sorted" buffer will be to small, fix: https://godbolt.org/z/hch9vGcGv
2. The variables should be, if they meaningfully can be, initialized when declared, and only declared when needed, NOT on the top of the function, fix: https://godbolt.org/z/njbGdaavP
(these two for now just cosmetic, more in the following comments)

Comment: 3. The checking code is weird, as it always show 7 first elements of the array (and crashes if there is less(, let's just remove it. 4. PROPER FIX - yes, the line you thought is wrong was indeed wrong - in merge sort, you put data in buffer at the same positions, that they should be in the original buffer. Instead, notice - you were always copying the same value (possibly out of array range). Fix: https://godbolt.org/z/fGhvYqx4b
5. More cosmetic fixes - the if-else is unnecessary, the same condition is taken care already in the for loop, fix: https://godbolt.org/z/zEz6KEqEe

Comment: You might be surprised, that the error showed up on a different line - unfortunately, that is the case with C++, memory corruption can be often detected much later. To get better diagnostics 1) use standard containers like std::vector, with that if you are using MSVC you will get good diagnostics out of bounds, if you are using g++ consider -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG compilation flag 2) if you are on linux and using g++/clang, consider Address Sanitizer and UB Sanitizer - tools, that usually come with the compiler and are very helpful to detect errors like that. 3) try debugging with Valgrind tool